# Is there a way to solve issue of Http failure response error?

Tags: angular, angular8, server-side-rendering

After running my application using **node dist/server.js** command and  I typed localhost:3111 at that time I have faced below error code issue.

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers:
   HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url:
   'http://localhost:3111/http://unifiedbackend.localhost.com/api/front/home/menu',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message:
   'Http failure response for http://localhost:3111/http://unifiedbackend.localhost.com/api/front/home/menu: 0 Unknown Error',
  error:
   ProgressEvent {
     type: 'error',
     target:
      XMLHttpRequest {
        onloadstart: null,
        onprogress: null,
        onabort: null,
        onerror: null,
        onload: null,
        ontimeout: null,
        onloadend: null,
        _listeners: [Object],
        onreadystatechange: null,
        _anonymous: undefined,
        readyState: 4,
        response: null,
        responseText: '',
        responseType: 'text',
        responseURL: '',
        status: 0,
        statusText: '',
        timeout: 0,
        upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
        _method: 'GET',
        _url: [Url],
        _sync: false,
        _headers: [Object],
        _loweredHeaders: [Object],
        _mimeOverride: null,
        _request: null,
        _response: null,
        _responseParts: null,
        _responseHeaders: null,
        _aborting: null,
        _error: null,
        _loadedBytes: 0,
        _totalBytes: 0,
        _lengthComputable: false },
     currentTarget:
      XMLHttpRequest {
        onloadstart: null,
        onprogress: null,
        onabort: null,
        onerror: null,
        onload: null,
        ontimeout: null,
        onloadend: null,
        _listeners: [Object],
        onreadystatechange: null,
        _anonymous: undefined,
        readyState: 4,
        response: null,
        responseText: '',
        responseType: 'text',
        responseURL: '',
        status: 0,
        statusText: '',
        timeout: 0,
        upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
        _method: 'GET',
        _url: [Url],
        _sync: false,
        _headers: [Object],
        _loweredHeaders: [Object],
        _mimeOverride: null,
        _request: null,
        _response: null,
        _responseParts: null,
        _responseHeaders: null,
        _aborting: null,
        _error: null,
        _loadedBytes: 0,
        _totalBytes: 0,
        _lengthComputable: false },
     lengthComputable: false,
     loaded: 0,
     total: 0 } }
```

Comment: Ok, it is an unknown error, how are we supposed to know what it is? Only thing I see spontaneously is the weird looking url. Why does it contain 2 concatenated urls? Isn't it supposed to be only `http://localhost:3111/api/front/home/menu'` ?

Comment: Actually, URL should be **http://unifiedbackend.localhost.com/api/front/home/menu** this but how this append in an express server that I couldn't know.

Comment: Then you should find out on which point the localhost is set in the url. Could be for example within an interceptor

Comment: I think I might have done some configuration on server.ts . i need to write some rule i think.